# Connect R to an API, pass it username and password

Tags: python, r, httr

I have been trying to retrieve data from an API using R, but haven't succeeded yet. I tried doing it in R using the httr package and the GET function, but I get the following error when I enter the URL:

Error: 'new_handle' is not an exported object from 'namespace:curl'

What it comes down to is that I want to connect to data and that I have to pass some arguments like password and username.

I do have some Python code from a colleague that works (I have anonymized the URLs that are specific to our company), what I want is to connect to the data in a similar way in R:

------------- Equivalent Python code: --------------

```
import urllib
import datetime as dt 
import dateutil
import json

headers = {u'content-type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
values = {"grant_type": "password",
      "username": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "password": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "client_id": "PS"}
ko = urllib.request.Request("XXXXXX",
                        urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8"),
                        headers)
token = urllib.request.urlopen(ko).read()
epic = token.decode()
token_key = epic.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].replace('"', "")
lines_to_write = list()
lines_to_write.append("Identifier;Year;Period;Park Energy Availability [%]")
start_day = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
data_day = start_day
headers = {u'content-type': u'application/json', u'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_key}
values = {'scope': {}, 'period': {'Begin': str(data_day).replace(" ", "T"), 'End': str(data_day + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).replace(" ", "T")}}
hest = urllib.request.Request("XXXXXXXXX", json.dumps(values).encode(), headers)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(hest)
vild_hest = data.read()
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Best regards,
Tristan

Comment: Can you also post the R code that resulted in the error?

Comment: library(httr)
    url="XXXXXXX"
    GET(url)

Comment: Have you looked at `?GET`? You can pass authentication info with `GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))`. Maybe try that? You can also send `config` settings if you need the other parts of `values` in your code.

Comment: I have tried using authenticate, using my own username and password, but I still get the same error  **Error: 'new_handle' is not an exported object from 'namespace:curl'**

Answer (score 0):

The R code for API you presented will not work since it is just simply fractions of what is needed. Below you find the structure that R needs for working towards a REST API. The username and password will be passed to API server through the body of the POST (either as stated below or it could also be added as a list in the body).

You will also have to provide a key (in below case "API-KEY"). Note that you are sending a POST to initiate the authentication with the API server. Most API server will send you back 1 or 2 keys that you will use in later communication with the API server.

It is correct that all http interaction will take help of the package httr.
GET will be used in later stage in the communication between your API client and API server but not during the first authentication phase.

```
POST (
url = "xxx", 
add_headers( 
"API-KEY" = "xxx",
"VERSION" = "2", 
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
"Accept" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"), 
body = "{identifier: xxx, password: xxx}"
)
```